# Prevent Users from changing date/time settings in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, users

I require to prevent the users from changing the date and time settings in ubuntu 18.04 using the GUI and If possible need to restrict the commands related to the same too.

Comment: Are you talking about the system clock or about the user time zone?

Comment: System Clock which is displayed in ribbon .

Comment: This can be changed by either changing the system clock or changing the timezone. What are you trying to solve? You want to make sure the time is accurate in screenshots and this serves as some proof?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the screenshot as proofs.

Comment: If the user aren't root they can't change the system time. The timezone can be changed by just setting an environment variable (and the time zone is also an option in the clock widget in the ribbon). Other workarounds can be editing the screenshot, or changing the clock widget that displays the time (source code is easy to find) to display any time you want. IMHO any solution that relies on what happens on the user's machine can be worked around. Make them upload the screenshots to a server, and use the time of upload.